# AJAX value from PHP returned as undefined with JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have an `AJAX` script updating a database via `PHP`.

I am then trying to return two variables back to the `AJAX` success function.

Currently, when alerting the data returned they are showing `UNDEFINED`.

When I return the `JSON` without stating the part of the array I require, the array displays in full. But only when I state specifically which value from the array I wish to use, I seem to get undefined on both values.

`How should I manage these values returned from the PHP?`

**The AJAX**

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#'+data.toUpdate).html(data.quant);
    $('#'+data.toUpdate).addClass('updated_grn');
    alert('quant:' + data.quant + '\nid:' + data.toUpdate);  
}
```

**The PHP**

```
if ($query) {
    echo json_encode(array("toUpdate" => $toUpdate, "quant" => $quant));
}
```

**The Result**

[image: Ajax returns Undefined]

When I `alert(data)` this is returned:

[image: Returned data]

**The full php**

```
$itemid   = ($_POST['itemid']);
$quant    = ($_POST['quant']);
$toUpdate = ($_POST['toUpdate']);

$sql = "UPDATE items_list
        SET `stock_level` = '$quant'
        WHERE item_id = '$itemid'";

$query = mysql_query($sql);

if ($query) {
    echo json_encode(array("toUpdate" => $toUpdate, "quant" => $quant));
}
```

**The full AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    type:     'POST',
    url:      url,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        itemid:   itemid,
        quant:    quant,
        toUpdate: toUpdate
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#'+id+'_num')
            .html("<img src='xxxxxxx.com/home/secure/images/gif/ajax-loader.gif'></img>");
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        //  $('#'+data.toUpdate).html(data.quant);
        //  $('#'+data.toUpdate).addClass('updated_grn');
        //  alert('quant:' + data.quant + '\nid:' + data.toUpdate);
    }
});
```

Comment: Updated question with full code and image.

Comment: What happens if you change `dataType: 'html'` to `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Change your AJAX dataType to json

Comment: oh wow. Don't i feel silly now. Thank you, if you answer i shall tick yours as correct, many thanks. @Darren

Comment: @StuartWickenden It's a pleasure :) I too ran into that issue once upon a time and felt like a complete idiot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `dataType: 'html'` to `dataType: 'json'` :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `$query` is true. I would also do `die()` so nothing else is in output:

```
 if ($query) {
    die(json_encode(array("toUpdate" => $toUpdate, "quant" => $quant)));
}
```

You can always check what you get from **PHP**:

```
success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $('#'+data.toUpdate).html(data.quant);
        $('#'+data.toUpdate).addClass('updated_grn');
        alert('quant:'+data.quant+'\nid:'+data.toUpdate);  
}
```

Comment: updated, the data returns in the array when `alert(data)`. Illustrated in question.

Comment: Use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) like this: `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); alert(obj.quant);`

Answer (score 0):

FYI.
I found this problem when using WordPress (4.3.1) and tried to load json data to D3.json function inside WordPress. json_encode(some_array) did not work but returned undefined. It returned a single integer value but not any array. UTF-8 check or anything else did not help.

Then incidently I closed the php ajax function by wp_die() command, it was missing there. And voila!, this suddenly works, json_encode returns array fine.

Hopefully this helps someone.